# Essentially surjective property is closed under composition of functors.

Tags: category-theory

I want to prove the essentially surjective property is closed under composition of functors.

A functor $F: C \to C'$ is essentially surjective if for each $Y \in C'$ there's an $X \in C$ such that $F(X) \xrightarrow{\sim} Y$.

My attempt: Let $F, G$ be functors with this property and suppose that $G \circ F$ is defined.  For any $Z \in C''$ there is $Y \in C'$ such that $\varphi: G(Y) \xrightarrow{\sim} Z$, where we also have $\psi: F(X) \xrightarrow{\sim} Y$.  Can't figure out what to do here, since I'm working in a category and not necessarily in **Set**.

Comment: Do you know the proof that surjective maps are closed under composition? Now take this proof and replace every $=$ by $\cong$.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjxf-eQWKoo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just recall that functors take isomorphisms to isomorphisms. Thus $G(\psi): G(F(X)) \xrightarrow{\sim} G(Y)$, and so the composition $\varphi \circ G(\psi): G(F(X)) \xrightarrow{\sim} Z$ is the desired isomorphism.

Comment: That was fast, thanks!  I will look at this in more detail...

Comment: I have changed $G \circ F(X)$ to $G(F(X))$. Another way of writing this is $(G \circ F)(X)$, but $G \circ F(X)$ is wrong, because this means the composition of $G$ with $F(X)$, which only would make sense if $F(X)$ is a functor. The same mistake is done quite often for functions.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I think "wrong" is a bit of an overstatement. When writing $G \circ F(X)$, one should think of $G \circ F$ as being a single symbol/name to which $X$ is applied. Why would someone think of it this way instead of assuming $F(X)$ is a functor which is being composed with $G$? Because of the context, of course! As with many mathematical notations, what I wrote sacrificed clarity for simplicity, but with context, the meaning is clear, so this sacrifice is warranted IMO.

Comment: Basically I agree, but when I read $g \circ f(x)$, I read this as follows: Ok, we have $g$. This is composed ... with what? With $f(x)$. No way, this cannot be true, because of the context. Ok, then probably this is $g \circ f$, and then we apply $x$. Yeah, this makes sense. ... Now compare this to $(g \circ f)(x)$. We see directly what's happening here.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I agree that your notation is clearer and less ambiguous, but one should be aware that the notation $g \circ f(x)$ is not uncommon.

Comment: Yes, the notation is common. That's true. I won't use it, for the reasons above. Of course, you can change it back in your answer everytime.

Comment: @AlexG. In a context, like this one at M.SE, where you are teaching/explaining something, it is better to be unambiguous since the OP is probably less experienced than yourself with a specific subject matter